# How to catch the moment when the parent control has been resized?

Tags: delphi, resize, components, parent-child, parent

I have a visual component derived from TWinControl. I need to do some work in my component when its parent control has been resized. In general case, the "Align" property of my component is alNone.

How to catch the event of resizing the parent control? Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a TWinControl (the parent) is changed in size, then `TWinControl.Realign` is called in the `WM_SIZE` handler. This bubbles via `TWinControl.AlignControls` into iterating over all the child controls which have the Align property set to anything else then `alNone`. When set to `alCustom`, `SetBounds` of the child controls will be called with unchanged arguments, even if their size has or has not changed due to anchor involvement.

So, set Align to `alCustom` and you have the *notification* of the parent's resize:

```
  TChild = class(T...Control)
  private
    FInternalAlign: Boolean;
    function GetAlign: TAlign;
    procedure ParentResized;
    procedure SetAlign(Value: TAlign);
  protected
    procedure RequestAlign; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    procedure SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer); override;
  published
    property Align: TAlign read GetAlign write SetAlign default alCustom;
  end;

constructor TChild.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Align := alCustom;
end;

function TChild.GetAlign: TAlign;
begin
  Result := inherited Align;
end;

procedure TChild.ParentResized;
begin
end;

procedure TChild.RequestAlign;
begin
  FInternalAlign := True;
  try
    inherited RequestAlign;
  finally
    FInternalAlign := False;
  end;
end;

procedure TChild.SetAlign(Value: TAlign);
begin
  if Value = alNone then
    Value := alCustom;
  inherited Align := Value;
end;

procedure TChild.SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
begin
  if not FInternalAlign then
    if (Align <> alCustom) or ((ALeft = Left) and (ATop = Top) and
        (AWidth = Width) and (AHeight = Height)) then
      ParentResized;
  inherited SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight);
end;
```

The only drawback I can think of for now is that the Align property can never be `alNone`, which could confuse the user of your component. It is easily possible to show or return `alNone` when the internal inherited property is still set to `alCustom`, but that is not an advice and would confuse only more. Just consider the `alCustom` setting as a feature of this component.

Note: with this construction, the user of your component is still able to implement custom alignment himself.

And here is my test code. Maybe you want add some testing for yourself.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, SysUtils, Classes, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    TestButton: TButton;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TestButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FChild: TControl;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

type
  TChild = class(TGraphicControl)
  private
    FInternalAlign: Boolean;
    function GetAlign: TAlign;
    procedure ParentResized;
    procedure SetAlign(Value: TAlign);
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
    procedure RequestAlign; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    procedure SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer); override;
  published
    property Align: TAlign read GetAlign write SetAlign default alCustom;
  end;

{ TChild }

constructor TChild.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Align := alCustom;
end;

function TChild.GetAlign: TAlign;
begin
  Result := inherited Align;
end;

procedure TChild.Paint;
begin
  Canvas.TextRect(ClientRect, 2, 2, 'Parent resize count = ' + IntToStr(Tag));
end;

procedure TChild.ParentResized;
begin
  Tag := Tag + 1;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TChild.RequestAlign;
begin
  FInternalAlign := True;
  try
    inherited RequestAlign;
  finally
    FInternalAlign := False;
  end;
end;

procedure TChild.SetAlign(Value: TAlign);
begin
  if Value = alNone then
    Value := alCustom;
  inherited Align := Value;
end;

procedure TChild.SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
begin
  if not FInternalAlign then
    if (Align <> alCustom) or ((ALeft = Left) and (ATop = Top) and
        (AWidth = Width) and (AHeight = Height)) then
      ParentResized;
  inherited SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight);
end;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FChild := TChild.Create(Self);
  FChild.SetBounds(10, 10, 200, 50);
  FChild.Parent := Self;
end;

procedure TForm1.TestButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  OldCount: Integer;
begin
  OldCount := FChild.Tag;

  Width := Width + 25;                                                     //1
  MoveWindow(Handle, Left, Top, Width + 25, Height, True);                 //2
  SetWindowPos(Handle, HWND_TOP, Left, Top, Width + 25, Height,
    SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSENDCHANGING or SWP_SHOWWINDOW);                   //3

  FChild.Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akRight];
  Width := Width + 25;                                                     //4
  MoveWindow(Handle, Left, Top, Width + 25, Height, True);                 //5
  SetWindowPos(Handle, HWND_TOP, Left, Top, Width + 25, Height,
    SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSENDCHANGING or SWP_SHOWWINDOW);                   //6

  FChild.Anchors := [akLeft, akTop];
  Panel1.Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akRight];
  FChild.Parent := Panel1;                                                 //7
  Width := Width + 25;                                                     //8
  MoveWindow(Handle, Left, Top, Width + 25, Height, True);                 //9
  SetWindowPos(Handle, HWND_TOP, Left, Top, Width + 25, Height,
    SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSENDCHANGING or SWP_SHOWWINDOW);                   //10

  FChild.Align := alRight;
  Width := Width + 25;                                                     //11
  MoveWindow(Handle, Left, Top, Width + 25, Height, True);                 //12
  SetWindowPos(Handle, HWND_TOP, Left, Top, Width + 25, Height,
    SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSENDCHANGING or SWP_SHOWWINDOW);                   //13

  if FChild.Tag = OldCount + 13 then
    ShowMessage('Test succeeded')
  else
    ShowMessage('Test unsuccessful');
end;

end.
```

Comment: I've tested all the solutions, and this one is the most stable I think. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Andrew, I think attaching your component to parent's message loop (subclassing it) is the way to go. For that you can use `TControl.WindowProc` property. The [doc](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TControl.WindowProc) explains that you have to save the original and restore it later (in the destructor of your component) and also to pass the messages to the original handler, ie your replacement should look like

```
procedure TMyComponent.SubclassedParentWndProc(Var Msg: TMessage);
begin
   FOldParentWndProc(Msg);
   if(Msg.Message = WM_SIZE)then begin
      ...
   end; 
end;
```

If you want to do it "old shool" way, use the [SetWindowLongPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API with `GWLP_WNDPROC` but AFAIK the `WindowProc` was introduced exactly for the reason to make it easier to subclass components, ie there is nothing wrong using it.

Comment: Replacing the window procedure is not the same as attaching to the parent's message loop. In fact, attaching to the parent's message loop doesn't make sense. Windows don't have message loops. Threads do have message queues which are pumped by a message loop. And in this instance, the `WM_SIZE` message is not delivered via the queue, it is a sent message.

Comment: Yeah, wrong wording on my part... but idea itself (hook to parent's wndprc) should work.

Comment: There *is* something wrong using WindowProc, which is the same thing that's wrong with using SetWindowLong: create control 1, create control 2, delete control 1, and watch your program crash as it tries to call the window procedure of a control that doesn't exist anymore. Use [SetWindowSubclass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762102.aspx) instead.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: It's good that you have proposed some existing solution to solve the "multiple instance problem", because I've just started to invent my own mechanism how to avoid this. :) I'll implement this solution ASAP and will write down the working code (I hope).

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: I'm almost there, but how to control the subclass IDs - since there's be one for each control? I cannot use ComponentIndex or ControlIndex because of collisions - what you suggest?

Comment: @Fabricio What about object's address - that should be unique?

Answer (score 1):

WARNING: Full rewrite. Thanks Rob!!

Example using SetWindowSubClass.

```
unit Example;

interface

uses
  Windows, Classes, Controls, StdCtrls, Messages, CommCtrl, ExtCtrls;

type
  TExampleClass = class(TlistBox)
  private
    procedure ActivateParentWindowProc;
    procedure RevertParentWindowProc;
  protected
    procedure SetParent(AParent: TWinControl); override;
  public
    procedure Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation); override;


  end;

function SubClassWindowProc(hWnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM;
         lParam: LPARAM; uIdSubclass: UINT_PTR; dwRefData: DWORD_PTR): LRESULT; stdcall;
implementation


procedure TExampleClass.ActivateParentWindowProc;
begin
  SetWindowSubClass( Parent.Handle, SubClassWindowProc, NativeInt(Self), 0);
end;


procedure TExampleClass.Notification(AComponent: TComponent;
  Operation: TOperation);
begin
  inherited Notification(AComponent, Operation);
  if (Operation = opRemove) and (AComponent = Parent) then
  begin
    RevertParentWindowProc;
  end;
end;


procedure TExampleClass.RevertParentWindowProc;
begin
  RemoveWindowSubclass( Parent.Handle,
                        SubClassWindowProc, NativeInt(Self));
end;

procedure TExampleClass.SetParent(AParent: TWinControl);
begin
  if Assigned(Parent) then
  begin
    RevertParentWindowProc;
  end;
  inherited SetParent(AParent);
  if Assigned(AParent) then
  begin
    ActivateParentWindowProc;
  end
  else
  begin
    RevertParentWindowProc;
  end;

end;

function SubClassWindowProc(hWnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT;
  wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM; uIdSubclass: UINT_PTR;
  dwRefData: DWORD_PTR): LRESULT;
begin
  if uMsg = WM_SIZE then
  begin
    // ...

  end;

  Result := DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);


end;

end.
```

Comment: In focussing on the implementation of the answer, you've lost sight of the question, which was to to be notified of events that occur to the *parent* control. You can't override methods of external classes, especially when you don't know what those classes will be until after you've already shipped your product.

Comment: @Fabricio Araujo: something is wrong with this code, because SetWindowSubClass always returns FALSE. Maybe because the Parent property is assigned when the Parent's window handle still not exists?

Comment: @Fabricio Araujo: I edited your solution a little (added the resize handler). It works great when I create the component's instance from the code, but when I place it on a form, it doesn't work, see my previous comment.

Comment: @Andrew: I guess so.  I'll try to solve that problem later today.

Comment: I'm trying to create an instance `LB: TExampleClass` dynamically like so: `procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LB := TExampleClass.Create(Self);
  LB.SetBounds(Edit1.Left, Edit1.Top + Edit1.Height + Edit1.Top, Edit1.Width, LB.Height);
  LB.Parent := Self;
end;` and it crashes when closing the app. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution to a similar problem. But in my case I cannot have such restrictions on alignment, and subclassing seemed overkill (the alignment thingie looks overkill too, now that I look at it)

So I came up with the following idea:

```
type
  TMyComponent = class(TControl)
  private
    FParentLastWidth: integer;
  ...
    procedure Invalidate; override;
  ...
  end;

procedure TMyComponent.Invalidate;
begin
  if (Parent <> nil) and (FParentLastWidth <> Parent.Width) then
  begin
    FParentLastWidth := Parent.Width;
    // do whatever when the parent resizes
  end;
  inherited;
end;
```

Add or replace the FParentLastWidth with whatever size you are tracking (I only needed reaction when the parent width changed. You can take it as an optimization so to not react to all kinds of changes which makes no difference for your component)

Comment: Remember that child controls do not always get repainted when the parent resizes [in one direction](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11775744/757830).

Comment: You're right. I have some custom draw stuff going on the parent form, that could explain why it's working in all my tried cases. Removing those, will only get it working when the child control is somehow affected by the resize.

Answer (score -1):

Here is exapmle to help you:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var newMethod: TMethod;
begin
  newMethod.Code := MethodAddress('OnResizez'); //your action for parent resize
  newMethod.Data := Pointer(self);
  SetMethodProp(button1.Parent, 'OnResize',  newMethod); //set event to button1.parent
end;

procedure TForm1.OnResizez(Sender: TObject);
begin
  button1.Width :=   button1.Width+1; //action on resize
end;
```

Comment: This isn't good idea - the OP writes custom control and control shouldn't use it's parent **event properties**; what if user of the control wants to use the event too?

Comment: It is just exapmle. Solution is: assign resize method to all TWinControl and call all OnParentResize for childs with Interface IResizeAction (or something like that) when OnResize fired.

Comment: Can I hook the message loop somehow instead and catch the WM_SIZE for parent's handle?

Comment: @Andrew It doesn't arrive via the message loop. `WM_SIZE` is delivered synchronously. You could replace the parent's window procedure I suppose but I'd expect there to be a much better solution than that.