# How can I detect changes to text and selection from my Notepad++ plug-in?

Tags: delphi, events, plugins, notepad++

Developing a Notepad++ plug-in using Delphi (using NPP's [DelphiPluginTemplate](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/DelphiPluginTemplate/) as a basis), how do I create event handlers like onSelectionChanged, onChange, etc.?

I imagine creating a function like this and then registering it somehow with Notepad++:

```
procedure onTextChanged(...); stdcall;
begin
  ShowMessage('Text was changed');
end;
...
initialization
RegisterMyNotepadPlusPlusOnChangeEvent(onTextChanged);
```

Comment: This question reads strangely. First you ask how to create things, but then you ask for the documentation of those things. Things that you create are, by definition not documented. Could you clarify please because I think there is confusion in the terminology.

Comment: I doubt you're going to find any documentation other than what comes with the Delphi plugin template.  People might be able to help you figure it out if you try something, and post your code.  Without code, this question is unlikely to get a useful answer.

Comment: What part of code do you want me to put? Code of DelphiPluginTemplate  is located in http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/DelphiPluginTemplate/ . I just want to put onChangeEvebnt to plugin. Putting here source of plugin is bad idea. Added code illustrating what i just need.

Comment: @David: Not really. If you want to provide implementations for event handlers -- which sounds like what's going on here -- then the rules for those events and event handlers must be documented by the API of the plug-in system that you're working with.

Comment: @Tomalak I read it as creating the mechanism to fire events, rather than implementing methods than can be event handlers.

Comment: @David: Sounds like that would be programming Notepad++, not a Notepad++ plug-in. :)

Answer (score 2):

Notepad++ doesn't appear to expose that information to plug-ins, but it does expose [the underlying Scintilla edit control](http://www.scintilla.org/), which provides numerous notifications to its container window via `wm_Notify` messages.

When the selection changes, the notification code is [`scn_UpdateUI`](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCN_UPDATEUI), and the `updated` field will include `sc_Update_Selection`.

When the text changes, the code is [`scn_Modified`](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCN_MODIFIED), and the `modificationType` field will indicate what was modified, which controls which other fields will have useful information.

Those messages are sent to the edit control's parent, which Notepad++ doesn't necessarily expose. It exposes the handles to two Scintilla controls, and you can call [`GetParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633510.aspx) to find the window that it notifies. Then you can [subclass it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762102.aspx), providing your own replacement window procedure that handles the notification messages you're interested in and then forwards everything to the next window procedure in the subclass list.

Comment: Is it possible to place here an example of replacing window message handler (with forwaring messages to original handler)?

Comment: @Astro - see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923432/how-to-catch-the-moment-when-the-parent-control-has-been-resized/6932832#6932832) for example code, usage of 'uIdSubclass' there is confusing though, pass instead '0' or '1' etc.., if you need a pointer in the callback (e.g. Self) pass as 'dwRefData'.

Comment: This example does not work for me. I just put example source to new unit, created TExampleClass component on form, and SubClassWindowProc does not seem to be called. I also have access violation exception when closing form. So i think this is not good example :(

Answer (score 2):

use beNotified. it's enough to get information about changes. if you use default Delphi headers - you must change BeNotified in TnppPlugin from normal method to virtual. and override it in your class.

```
procedure TIHelpPlugin.BeNotified(sn: PSCNotification);
begin
  inherited;
  if NppData.NppHandle <> HWND(sn.nmhdr.hwndFrom) then begin
    case sn.nmhdr.code of
      SCN_UPDATEUI,SCN_MODIFIED,SCN_CHARADDED: begin
        onTextChanged(...);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```